# I want to extract Url from an anchor tag in ui path

Tags: uipath

I'm looking for a way to extract URLs from an anchor tag, anchor tag are rendering like this in DOM.

```
<a target="_blank" id="Tile_WPQ8_1_3" href="#" onclick="PreventDefaultNavigation(); return false;" hrefaction="https://institutes.kpmg.us/global-energy/webcasts/2020/resilience-in-energy-3.html" clickaction="null"></a>
```

I want the value of ***hrefaction***, I'm trying below code- it's a Data scraping

```
<extract>
    <column name2='Url' attr2='href' exact='0' name='Name' attr='text'>
        <webctrl tag="a"/>
    </column>
</extract>
```

but it is giving me just **href** value but as we can see in above pattern value present in **hrefaction**
Ant lead highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Get Attribute](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/get-attribute) activity of UI path, to get the value of attribute that you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

And if the Get Attribute is not working because you cannot access the web element or you get the data from somewhere else you can still use a simple **regex** like this:

[image]

using the expression `hrefaction="(.+)"` .